How do I solve this system of PDE'S?
I am having trouble solving this system of PDE's that I got from a big problem

$$\partial_\phi B(\phi) + \sin^2(\theta) \partial_\theta C(\theta, \phi) = 0$$
$$\partial_\phi C(\theta, \phi) + B(\phi) \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 0$$

The first equation is:
$$ \partial_\phi B(\phi) + \sin^2(\theta) \partial_\theta C(\theta, \phi) = 0 $$
This equation suggests that $\partial_\phi B(\phi)$ is a function that is independent of $\theta$, while $\sin^2(\theta) \partial_\theta C(\theta, \phi)$ must be balanced by it. Since $\partial_\phi B(\phi)$ is a function of $\phi$ alone, let's integrate both sides with respect to $\phi$:
$$ \partial_\phi B(\phi) = - \sin^2(\theta) \partial_\theta C(\theta, \phi) $$
To simplify, recognize that $\partial_\phi B(\phi)$ must be a constant, say $k$:
$$\partial_\phi B(\phi) = k $$
$$ B(\phi) = k\phi + b $$
where $b$ is an integration constant.
So, the equation now becomes:
$$ k = - \sin^2(\theta) \partial_\theta C(\theta, \phi) $$
$$ \partial_\theta C(\theta, \phi) = -\frac{k}{\sin^2(\theta)}$$
Integrate with respect to $\theta$:
$$ C(\theta, \phi) = \int -\frac{k}{\sin^2(\theta)} d\theta$$
$$ C(\theta, \phi) = k \cot(\theta) + f(\phi) $$
where $f(\phi)$ is an arbitrary function of $\phi$.
The second equation is:
$$ \partial_\phi C(\theta, \phi) + B(\phi) \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 0 $$
Substitute the expressions for $B(\phi) $ and $C(\theta, \phi)$:
$$ \partial_\phi (k \cot(\theta) + f(\phi)) + (k \phi + b) \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 0 $$
$$ \partial_\phi f(\phi) + (k \phi + b) \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 0 $$
This separates into:
$$ \partial_\phi f(\phi) + k \phi \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} + b \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 0 $$
$$ \partial_\phi f(\phi) = -k \phi \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} - b \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} $$
Since this equation must hold for all $\theta$, the terms involving $\theta$ and $\phi$ must separately be constants. Hence, the only way this equation can hold for all $\theta$ is if:
$$ \partial_\phi f(\phi) = 0 $$
$$ k \phi = 0 $$
$$ b = 0 $$
Given $k \phi = 0$, there are two possibilities:

$k = 0$: In this case, $B(\phi)$ becomes a constant and $C(\theta, \phi)$ simplifies accordingly.

So, let's consider the case $k = 0$:
If $k = 0$, then:
$$ B(\phi) = b $$
$$ C(\theta, \phi) = f(\phi) $$
From the second equation:
$$ \partial_\phi f(\phi) + b \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 0 $$
For this to hold for all $\theta$, $b = 0$. Thus,
$$ B(\phi) = 0 $$
$$ C(\theta, \phi) = \text{constant} $$
The solutions  are:
$$ B(\phi) = 0 $$
$$ C(\theta, \phi) = \text{constant} $$
However I know that the solution should be $B(\phi)=-D\sin\phi +E\cos\phi and C(\theta,\phi)=-\cot \theta (D\cos\phi +E\sin\phi)+F$, with D,E,F constants that I checked verifies the original system
What am I doing wrong? How do I solve the system then?

In the wording of the problem $B(\phi)$ is written. It is not written $B(\theta, \phi)$. This is sufficient to say that $B$ is function of $\phi$ only. Thus the system of equations is :
$$\frac{dB(\phi)}{d\phi} =- \sin^2(\theta) \frac{\partial C(\theta,\phi)}{\partial\theta} \tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial C(\theta,\phi)}{\partial\phi} =- B(\phi) \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} \tag 2$$
Differentiating Eq.($1$) wrt $\phi$ :
$$\frac{d^2B}{d\phi^2} =- \sin^2(\theta) \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial\theta\partial \phi} \tag 3$$
Differentiating Eq.($2$) wrt $\theta$ :
$$\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial \theta\partial\phi} =- B \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\right)=B\frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)} \tag 4$$
Bringing Eq.($4$) into Eq.($3$) :
$$\frac{d^2B}{d\phi^2} =-B \tag 5$$
The well-known solution of this second order linear ODE is :
$$\boxed{B(\phi)=c_1 \sin(\phi)+c_2\cos(\phi)} \tag 6$$
Bringing $B$ from Eq.($6$) into Eq.($2$) :
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial\phi} =-\big(c_1 \sin(\phi)+c_2\cos(\phi) \big)\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} \tag 7$$
Integrating Eq.($7$) wrt $\phi$ :
$$\boxed{C(\theta,\phi) =\big(c_1 \cos(\phi)-c_2\sin(\phi) \big)\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} +F}\tag 8$$
$c_1\:,\:c_2\:,\:F$ are constant.
Note : In Eq.($8$) we should write $F(\theta)$. But bringing $C$ from Eq.($8$) into Eq.($1$) implies $F(\theta)=$constant. This eliminate the invalid solutions introduced by integration.
Eq.($8$) is the solution that you expected with $c_1=-D$ and $c_2=E$.
The mistake in your calculus seems in the line " To simplify, recognize that $\partial_\phi B(\phi)$ must be a constant ". It is still a function of $\phi$ which doesn't allows simplification.
